# Docker how to push image to artifactory with certificate signed

Tags: docker, artifactory

I woudlike to send my image to repository factory but I have this error when I try to run :

```
Docker push image
```

Error :

```
 x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the certificate being used by the Docker registry is not valid (according to your Docker client). You have a couple of ways to fix this:

1. Add a [self-signed certificate](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#use-self-signed-certificates) to the Docker client
2. Add the registry as an ["insecure registry"](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#deploy-a-plain-http-registry) to ignore the certificate issue
3. Use a valid, recognized certificate

The third is the ideal method since #1 and #2 would need to be done for any client you use with that registry. If you have control to do #3, I would recommend getting a valid cert ([LetEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) lets you generate one for free) and using it.

It is also possible, though less likely, that you are using a proxy or VPN that is between you and the registry and that has a certificate the client has a problem with. If that is the case, you can verify by trying to access it without the VPN/PROXY.